# Pulling a value from Asynchronus Function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm working with we sockets and I have a lot of requests, so I figured it'd be best to pull the data out of the asynchronus funtion and put it in a variable outside of it. My code looks like this but I just get request [Pending]:

```
var variable;
var Request = require("request");
function getAsyncValue() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            var object = JSON.parse(body);
            var value = object.data.available_balance;
            resolve(value);
          });
    });
}


async function asyncWrapper() {
    variable = await getAsyncValue();
    return(variable);
}

printVariable = asyncWrapper();
console.log(printVariable);
```

Any idea on how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

put your console.log inside the asyncWrapper() as following:

```
 async function asyncWrapper() { 
     variable = await getAsyncValue(); 
     console.log(printVariable); 
     return(variable); 
 } 

 printVariable = asyncWrapper();
```

the reason for doing this is because when u had console.log() after the asyncWrapper(), it will be called immediately and not in an sync manner as u would need.

or you can do the following:

Just wrap the asyncWrapper function call inside an another async method and await for the result of asynWrapper() in that. Look below:

```
var function1 = async function () {
    printVariable = await asyncWrapper();
    console.log(printVariable);
}
```

Comment: Still gives me Promise { <pending> }

Comment: wrap your method call into an another async and await call

Answer (score 0):

Your asyncWrapper is a promise. You have to use await.

To use an await, you need an async function. So you can use a IIFE(Immediately Invoked Functions Expressions) async function.

```
async function(){
    printVariable = await asyncWrapper();
    console.log(printVariable);
}();
```

Comment: Yeah that works and it's cool and all, but still I need to pull the value out of the function, as of now it's just printing the value inside the function

Comment: If you get me what I need: The asyncWrapper funtion needs to return a value to an outside variable... but so far if I do it it gives me Promise { <pending> }

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was looking for:

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var returnCode;
var getUrl = "url";

returnCode = httpGet(getUrl);
var object = JSON.parse(returnCode);
var balance = objekt.data.available_balance;

console.log(balance);

function httpGet(url){
  var response = request(
    'GET',
    url
    );
    return response.body;
}
```